# insert $ symbol in sql database

Tags: android, sql

How to insert $ symbol in the sql database in android?

When i'm trying to insert the $ and ' symbols.
it gives the errors as follows,

```
02-18 00:39:39.821: E/AndroidRuntime(946): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "$": INSERT INTO NoteLists (time, data, color) VALUES ('12:39:39 AM Feb 18, 2012', '&/:;()!@".,?'$<>','#D2FF00');
```

please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to escape them. `\$`and `''`.

Otherwise put those signs into a string and use parameter binding which is recommended for security reasons anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You should never put raw values directly into the query. That allows for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) which is a serious security vulnerability.

What you should do instead is create a [SQLiteStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html) object with [SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement%28java.lang.String%29) and then use the bind functions. For example:

```
s = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO NoteLists (time, data, color) VALUES (?, ?, ?);");
s.bindString(1, "12:39:39 AM Feb 18, 2012");
s.bindString(2, "()!@\".,?'$<>");
s.bindString(3, "#D2FF00");
s.executeInsert();
```

You can also try [InsertHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper.html). It may make things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The `$` is preceded by an unescaped `'`, which means that SQLite only parses `&/:;()!@".,?` as a string, and the remaining characters (`$<>`) cause a syntax overflow.

Try replacing `'` with `''` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The single quote between the `?` and the `$` needs to be escaped with two single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO NoteLists 
    (time, data, color)       
    VALUES                                    \/    
    ('12:39:39 AM Feb 18, 2012', '&/:;()!@".,?''$<>','#D2FF00');
                                              /\
```